# How to call method on UITextField after editing in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField on which I'm calling the animation code below. It runs fine but this code runs when I press the return key. I want this code to automatically run after the user enters any data in the text field without pressing the return key.

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
       {
         [patientNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
[addressTextField resignFirstResponder];
         [doctortTextField resignFirstResponder];
     [self showAnimationBack];
         return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After entering any data means you can use this method.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
//do something here
return YES;
}
```

or use these methods.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;          // return YES to allow editing to stop and to resign first responder status. NO to disallow the editing session to end
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;             // may be called if forced even if shouldEndEditing returns NO (e.g. view removed from window) or endEditing:YES called
```

Answer (score 2):

Use UITextField's Delegate Method :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

This method will be called after every character you input in textfield.

```
return YES;
```

for implementing the change you do in this method. 
Else

```
return NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these delegate methods:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Comment: this method will be called while start of editing i want this method to call when user stops or finshes editing

Comment: How can you decide that user stops editing? So what we assume is when user taps return key, this following delegate will be called
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;

Secondly when user finishes typing in textfield, and then taps anywhere around on screen, then following method will be called.
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
{

 [patientNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
 [addressTextField resignFirstResponder];
 [doctortTextField resignFirstResponder];
 [self showAnimationBack];

}
```

Comment: this method will be called while start of editing i want this method to call when user stops or finshes editing

Comment: I have changed the method name